# ExtrapolationException. Very small time difference?

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently, I'm using IMU(Xsens) + Laser(Hokuyo).
Sometimes, below is problem. As you see, 0.04sec time difference. (Few sample difference). How can I solve this problem?

Note that all nodes are on same machine.

[ INFO] [1343387030.068372425]: lookupTransform base_stabilized to laser timed out. Could not transform laser scan into base_stabilized.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'tf::ExtrapolationException'
what():  Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.  Requested time 1343387030.103303000 but the latest data is at time 1343387030.065800000, when looking up transform from frame [/laser] to frame [/base_stabilized]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39968/extrapolationexception.-very-small-time-difference?/) by [Hyon Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/378/hyon-lim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 314 on 2012-07-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just use [waitForTransform](http://ros.org/doc/fuerte/api/tf/html/c++/classtf_1_1Transformer.html#a6d5a0ef43029723a4537102d5254b431) or [tf::MessageFilter](http://ros.org/doc/fuerte/api/tf/html/c++/classtf_1_1MessageFilter.html). Also, make sure you went through [this tutorial](http://ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials/tf%20and%20Time%20%28C%2B%2B%29).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The easy way would be to use 0 as the time, this will get you the latest data, instead of the data at the time (which might be in the future/no received yet).

Alternatively, use tf waitForTransform.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-07-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1